# Installing flash through an iframe...getting redirected back to the outer frame?

Tags: flash, iframe, redirect, adobe

I'm using adobe's example.swf to provide inline flash upgrades for users. However, if the example.swf is embedded in an iframe, and the user gets redirected, adobe will redirect them back to the inner iframe page, causing breakage.

Is there any way for this redirect to bring the user back to the outer frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your flashvars, set `MMredirectUrl` to your redirect url of choice. In this case, use `window.parent.location`.